# Virtual link in ASP.NET gives 404 error

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

I noticed something weird.
So normally in ASP.NET if you place a ~ in the beginning of a url, this symbol represents the root directory of the web site.

It works for all links I have on my .aspx page, except one for some reason, that points to a page located in the Account folder, where Identity's template pages are located.

So clicking this link gives me a 404 error, and asp.net informs me that the requested url was

> /~/Account/Login.aspx

Obviously it doesn't work in this case, as there is no folder named ~ in the file system. But why it doesn't work ?

Now if I remove the ~/ symbols, the link will work ONCE, but then if clicked twice, the browser will try to navigate to /Account/Account/Login.aspx, which will of course throw yet another 404 error.

[image]

What can I do to make it so each time the user clicks that link, it takes him to the Login.aspx page ?

Comment: How are you making the link in the first place?  What is the difference between a working link and this no-working link?

Comment: Well first I tried adding the link with the pop-up window in Visual Studio that shows ups every time you add a href attribute. The url of VS's auto complete for the href was "Account\Login.aspx", which is what gives a 404 error the second time one clicks the link.

Comment: Pop-up window?  What's the actual code?  If you use a relative path then, yes, it needs to be used from the correct relative location.  "Account/Login.aspx" isn't going to work from anything except the folder which contains the "Account" folder.

Comment: Whenever you add a href attribute, IntelliSense shows up with suggestions, to choose a local page to link to.  http://i.imgur.com/cGViPfL.png  If you don't see the desired page, you click on "Pick url", and a window pops up with a file browser, with which you choose the file, and the url on the href attribute is added automatically. http://i.imgur.com/4XzXVTH.png  Well this automatic url works the first time, but gives a 404 error the second time it's clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to a screen shot of code you provided in a comment, your actual code is:

```
<a href="~Account/Login.aspx">Login</a>
```

As far as URLs are concerned, there is no `~` path here.  There is a `~Account` path.  All as one word.  Which of course doesn't exist.

You *can* use the `~` path to indicate the root of the application, but you need to keep it as its own path:

```
<a href="~/Account/Login.aspx">Login</a>
```

Additionally, you *probably* need to explicitly tell the framework to apply server-side processing for this:

```
<a href="~/Account/Login.aspx" runat="server">Login</a>
```

Because if it sends the content to the browser as-is then the browser won't know what to do with the `~` path, that's only meaningful server-side.

Comment: Oh God! The omission of runat="server" was the troublemaker! I was trying all kinds of different stuff with the actual url, and hadn't noticed that. Thank you!